# Error al copear formatos de un libro a otro en excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy tratando de copear datos (en si formatos de un rango) de un libro a otro, pero en el último paso me sale error de Rango, a pesar de habler declarado anteriormente, alguno me podría indicar en que parte estoy errando, ya llevo tiempo y no logro identificar el error, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub Formatos()

Dim wbFormatos As Workbook
Dim wbPLANTILLA_DE_CARTERA As Workbook

Dim wsRESUMEN_DIRECTOR As Range
Dim wsD_RESUMEN_DIRECTOR As Range

Dim rutaOrigen As String
Dim rutaDestino As String

rutaOrigen = "D:\Formatos.xlsm"
rutaDestino = "D:\PLANTILLA DE CARTERA.xlsm"

Set wbFormatos = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=rutaOrigen, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
Set wbPlantillaDeCartera = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=rutaDestino, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)

'Hojas origen
Set wsRESUMEN_DIRECTOR = wbFormatos.Worksheets("RESUMEN DIRECTOR").Range("A1:AG60")

'Hojas destino
Set wsD_RESUMEN_DIRECTOR = wbPlantillaDeCartera.Worksheets("RESUMEN DIRECTOR").Range("A1:AG60")
wsRESUMEN_DIRECTOR.Copy: Range(wsD_RESUMEN_DIRECTOR).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

ThisWorkbook.Save
wbFormatos.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: "A1:AG60" este rango es correcto?

Comment: Buenos días. Si así es , ambas hojas manejan el mismo tamaño de la celda A1 hasta la AG60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu línea

`Range(wsD_RESUMEN_DIRECTOR).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` está llamando a un rango cuyo nombre/dirección está en la variable `wsD_RESUMEN_DIRECTOR` que es de tipo rango y no de tipo string. Eso es lo que confunde a Excel.

Prueba así:

```
wsRESUMEN_DIRECTOR.Copy: wsD_RESUMEN_DIRECTOR.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tenías razón.